# How can I download jdk files from Oracle via curl?

Tags: java, linux, macos, curl

I realized there are many websites explaining ways.

For me, I met a solution,

```
curl -s -j -k -L -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" -o jdk.dmg https://path.to/jdk.dmg
```

, which had worked long time.

Now it does not work on macOS (Catalina). the same command works in my Linux CentOS7.

curl version is curl 7.64.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0) for macOS.
7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) for CentOS 7.

How can I install by my macOS curl?

```
wget -q --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" https://path/to/jdk.dmg
```

does work ... in macOS. Cookie phrase must not be a source of problem...

Comment: Or avoid Oracle and download an alternative like adoptopenjdk, they allow direct downloads

Answer (score 1):

I would try SDKman. It works for both linux and MacOS and helps you manage JDK versions easily. Install instructions are found here: https://sdkman.io/install